# Cannot apply modifier via script despite object being active?

Tags: modifiers

I can't apply the modifier programmatically via Python, but clicking the GUI button works.

Some answers on this site say `bpy.ops` commands usually demand the current active object be proper.

```
>>> bpy.context.scene.objects.active
bpy.data.objects['Icosphere']
```

tells me my active object is proper.

But still, I get

```
>>> bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(apply_as='DATA')
{'CANCELLED'}
```

Again, clicking the GUI button works without problems. How may I do it via script?

---

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier='Mirror')
```

This command requires you to give it a modifier name.

```
bpy.ops.object.apply_all_modifiers()
```

This will apply all modifiers.  Note, this is a operator from addon 'Modifier Tools'.  You have to have this addon enabled to be able to use that command.

Comment: AttributeError: Calling operator "bpy.ops.object.apply_all_modifiers" error, could not be found

Comment: Sorry, that command is a subtool from the addon 'Modifier Tools'.  Do you have this addon?  If you do, enable it and try again.  If not, you have to get this addon, or just upgrade your blender to the newest version.  Then make sure it's enabled.